# How to process binary-encoded data without writing to file and importing?

Tags: import

I am consuming a webservice through NETLink that returns data directly in the response as a gzipped csv file.

I can successfully process the data like this:

```
binz=response@data
BinaryWrite["tmp.csv.gz", binz]
Close["tmp.csv.gz"]
Import["tmp.csv.gz", "CSV"]
```

However, I am curious if there is a more direct way to achieve this?  Thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 8):

The following seems to work:

```
(* Simulate your response *)
binz = ExportString[ {"A System for Doing", "Mathematics by Computer"}, {"GZIP", "CSV"} ];

(*Uncompress and read CSV*)
ImportString[binz, {"GZIP", "CSV"}]
(*
{{"A System for Doing"}, {"Mathematics by Computer"}}

*)
```

You may prefer to post a small data sample to test with your actual data format.

Answer (score 4):

Base64 binary to text encoding may help, ie:

```
turtle = Import["ExampleData/turtle.jpg"];
gif = ExportString[turtle, "GIF"];
encoded = ExportString[gif, "Base64"];
ImportString[encoded, "Base64"]
```

[image]

However, Mathematica 7 requires this method:

```
turtle = Import["ExampleData/turtle.jpg"];
encoded = ExportString[turtle, {"Base64", "GIF"}];
ImportString[encoded, "Base64"]
```

For sending through NETLink you can use this:

```
kernel.Compute("ExportString[Graphics[Rectangle[]],{\"Base64\",\"EMF\"}]");
byte[] decodedBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(kernel.Result.ToString());
File.WriteAllBytes("C:\\Temp\\output.emf", decodedBytes);
```

Comment: +1. Did not know the form `ExportString[expr, {"format", "format", ...}]`. Where is it documented? It is equivalent to `Fold[ExportString, 
 expr, Reverse@{"format", "format", ...}]`. For example, try: `ExportString[Graphics[Rectangle[]], {"UUE", "Base64", "UUE", "EMF"}] ===
  Fold[ExportString, Graphics[Rectangle[]], 
  Reverse@{"UUE", "Base64", "UUE", "EMF"}]`.

Comment: As far as I know the ExportString/ImportString combo uses temporary files to work on. So, although you're not explicitely using files, you're still doing it under the hood.

Comment: @ Alexey - I believe I found this syntax on the MathGroup. It doesn't seem to be eqivalent to `Fold` at least on Mma 7, since this does not work: `encoded = Fold[ExportString, turtle, {"GIF", "Base64"}];`